# Addressing sys.excepthook error in bash script

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix

I've written a bash script that is doing exactly what I want it to do, but kicking out the following error:

`close failed in file object destructor: sys.excepthook is missing lost sys.stderr`

I'm completely stumped on how to address this. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage () { echo "${0##*/} inputfile outputfile"; exit 1; }

(($#==2)) || usage

INPUTFILE="$1"
OUTPUTFILE="$2"

#  All that is written between between the 'cat' command and 
#+ 'EOF' will be sent to the output file.
cat <<EOF >$OUTPUTFILE
$(date "+Generated on %m/%d/%y at %H:%M:%S")

DATA AUDIT: $1

------------
COLUMN NAMES
------------

$(csvcut -n $INPUTFILE)

---------------------------------------
FIRST TEN ROWS OF FIRST FIVE COLUMNS 
---------------------------------------

$(csvcut -c 1,2,3,4,5 $INPUTFILE | head -n 10)

------------
COLUMN STATS
------------

$(csvcut $INPUTFILE | csvstat )

---END AUDIT
EOF

echo "Audited!"
```

I am pretty new to shell scripts and very new to python. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: The error comes from the python script (csvcut?), not from your bash script. It would be more useful to see its code relevant code instead :D

Comment: It might be that the csvcut does not like the head, as it forces the stdout of the process to close prematurely?

Comment: @Antti, I was guessing that to be the case, but wondering if there was something I could do in the script that would address the issue, since running the commands individually at the command line does not generate the error. Do you have an idea of how the head might be changed to address a possible stdout issue? Or would the csvcut code still be necessary for this? And thanks!

Comment: why are you running with command-substituions, i.e. `$(csvcut $INPUTFILE | csvstat )`, when all you need is `csvcut $INPUTFILE | csvstat`. Good luck.

Comment: Because it is a heredoc, no? What you are suggesting doesn't work. Am I misunderstanding? Hope you'll follow up, and thanks for chiming in.

Comment: doah! you're right.... here-doc ... good use of command-substition! NOte to self, read code more throughtly. Good luck.

Comment: I have to agree with others, the error message you're showing is not something any shell would output, and sounds linke it must be from python. You need to determine if it is the first csvcut, the last, or all of them that generate that error. Good luck.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was seeing this error when piping output from a Python 2.6.2 script into the `head` command in `bash` on Ubuntu 9.04. I added `try` blocks to close `stdout` and `stderr` before exiting the script:

```
try:
    sys.stdout.close()
except:
    pass
try:
    sys.stderr.close()
except:
    pass
```

I am no longer seeing the error.

Comment: Any explanation as to why this works? I've been getting this error in a cython script that does some redirection with dup/dup2 and this seems to fix things.

Comment: The solution also works with calls to `.flush` instead of `.close`. I don't know if this means anything though. (`close` implies `flush`). Python 2.7.8 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The `-u` option to python (unbuffered output) seems relevant too. When `-u` is passed, I am unable to replicate the problem

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps you need to perform:

Step 1:

In your **csvcut** script, find all locations where `sys.stdout.write()` are called, make sure `sys.stdout.flush()` is called after each `write()`.

Step 2:

With step 1 completed you should now be able to capture `IOError` within the Python script.  Below is one example on how to handle broken pipe:

```
try:
    function_with_sys_stdout_write_call()
except IOError as e:
    # one example is broken pipe
    if e.strerror.lower() == 'broken pipe':
        exit(0)
    raise       # other real IOError
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This was a proper fix in my case. Looks like a traceback was still being written to stderr while the script was quitting and flusing the stderr before quitting did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the `csvcut` Python script is otherwise functional but is throwing up an error when it tries to close files and exit.

If, as you say, the script is otherwise working and assuming that the error 'csvcut' is throwing up outputs to stderr then redirecting it to /dev/null would be a temp fix.

```
cat <<EOF >$OUTPUTFILE 2>/dev/null
```

Naturally any other error messages in your heredoc will also redirect there.

Comment: Even as a temp fix, that isn't working for me. Still getting the same error.