# rst2html.py print "close failed in file object destructor"

Tags: python

I write this command for checking long-description in setup.py.

```
python setup.py --long-description | rst2html.py > output.html
```

But it print this message.

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

I open output.html, but output.html is white paper.

My enviroment is Python 2.7.5 on windows.

Please advise.

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = "test", 
    version = "0.1",
    author = "test",
    author_email = "test@test.com",
    url = "test.com"
    packages = ["test"],
    license = "MIT License",
    description = "test",
    long_description = """
    ====
    test
    ====
    """,
    classifiers = [
        "Programming Language :: Python"
        ]
)
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `setup.py`? Giving that it's the writer of the pipe, I'd assume that it's the one raising the error.

Comment: I think that the issue is in `rst2html.py` side. Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8690674/661140

Comment: I read it, but I can't deal this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by

```
<Path to setup.py> pip install docutils
```

It doesn't appear Error.

But output.html is still whitepaper.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma missing in your `setup.py`:

```
    url = "test.com"
    packages = ["test"],
```

should be

```
    url = "test.com",
    packages = ["test"],
```

Additionally, your description is indented, and that breaks rst. Either use [`textwrap.dedent`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) or  don't indent it, like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

long_description = """
test
====

fooo
"""

setup(
    name="test",
    version="0.1",
    author="test",
    author_email="test@test.com",
    url="test.com",
    packages=["test"],
    license="MIT License",
    description="test",
    long_description=long_description,
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python"
    ]
)
```

Comment: close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr

Comment: Mmm, that's indeed strange. What output do you get when you run `python setup.py --longfile >tmp.txt`, `type tmp.txt`, `rst2html.py < tmp.txt >output.html`? Does the problem stay the same with a [current version](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) of the Python interpreter?

Comment: Error don't appear on Python 2.7.6.

Comment: python setup.py --longfile >tmp.txt result error: option --longfile not reconized

Comment: But output.html is still white paper.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the typo - I meant `python setup.py --long-description > tmp.txt`. In any case, your problem seems to be **solved by upgrading to 2.7.6**, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. "python setup.py --long-description > tmp.txt" result that long-deescription write tmp.txt. "type tmp.txt" result same as long-description. "rst2html.py < tmp.txt >output.html" result that output.html is whitepaper.

Comment: Sorry, this problem is solved by pip install docutils on <Path to setup.py>. not by upgrade Python