# subprocess Popen.stdin.write causes AttributeError

Tags: python, file, subprocess

I'm working on a short, native (do NOT recommend an outside [non-native] module such as pexpect), cross-platform, insecure remote control application for python (Windows will use py2exe and an exe file). I am using start_new_thread for the blocking calls such as `readline()`. For some reason, however, I get this string of ugliness as my output:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function read_stream at 0xb6918730>Unhandled exception in thread started by <function send_stream at 0xb69186f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in read_stream
    s.send(pipe.stdout.readline())
AttributeError  File "main.py", line 14, in send_stream
    pipe.stdin.write(s.recv(4096))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stdin'
: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stdout'
```

Here is my program (main.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import subprocess as sp
from thread import start_new_thread
from platform import system

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('10.0.0.201', 49200))
shell = 'powershell.exe' if system() == 'Windows' else '/bin/bash' # is this right?     
pipe = sp.Popen(shell, shell=True, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
entered_command=False
def send_stream(): # send what you get from command center
        while True:
                pipe.stdin.write(s.recv(4096))
def read_stream(): # send back what is returned from shell command
        while True:
                s.send(pipe.stdout.readline())
start_new_thread(send_stream, ())
start_new_thread(read_stream, ())
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `pipe` cannot be `None`. Maybe you could remove the socket stuff to create an easy [mcve]

Comment: Yes, that's suggesting `pipe` is None. Insert tests for this where created; if valid there, insert tests in the thread functions

Comment: Is for sure this __exact__ code that throws the error? I've read about the `subprocess.Popen` constructor that it would raise exceptions when things go wrong, but not returning `None`.

Comment: FYI, use `threading.Thread` instead of the low-level `thread` module. In Python 3 `thread` was renamed `_thread` to emphasize that it's not meant to be the public threading API in the standard library.

Comment: @JoeP Okay, I inserted tests. Inside the functions, `pipe` is none but outside them it is normal. Does that help?

Comment: Also, I tried passing `pipe` as `p` into the parameters and using `p` but I got this:
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr

Comment: Can you replicate this error in a non-threaded example? If not, can you convert to using threading.Thread as suggested above?

Comment: For the case where you get `sys.excepthook is missing` try searching on that error - eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955138/addressing-sys-excepthook-error-in-bash-script - it looks like it might be solvable.

Comment: I tried removing the threads and using synchronous stuff in a while loop, and what happened was I typed in a command and one line of the output would come out (as expected), and then I would hit enter, and it would print out the next line, etc., etc. but I could no longer type in any more commands after that; they did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem is that the program was trying to exit after the two `start_new_thread` calls because it had reached the end, and caused errors while trying to do so. So I replaced:

```
start_new_thread(send_stream, ())
start_new_thread(read_stream, ())
```

With:

```
start_new_thread(send_stream, ())
read_stream()
```